# Return Document with Max Sub Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to return a document with it's maximum subdocument based upon a date value. So far I am able to create the correct object, however the query is returning all subdocuments instead of the ones with the maximum date. For example, my data is stored as:

```
{ value: 1,
  _id: 5cb9ea0c75c61525e0176f96,
  name: 'Test',
  category: 'Development',
  subcategory: 'Programming Languages',
  status: 'Supported',
  description: 'Test',
  change:
   [ { version: 1,
       who: 'ATL User',
       when: 2019-04-19T15:30:39.912Z,
       what: 'Item Creation' },
     { version: 2,
       who: 'ATL Other User',
       when: 2019-04-19T15:30:39.912Z,
       what: 'Name Change' } ],
}
```

In my query I am selecting all items that have the same `subcategory`, as well with having their `name` exist. I then project all the values that I need within the object, unwind and sort the array, and return the query results. Structure wise, this gets me the correct output modeled here:

```
{
  _id: 5cb9ea0c75c61525e0176f96,
  name: 'Test',
  category: 'Development',
  subcategory: 'Programming Languages',
  status: 'Supported',
  description: 'Test',
  change: {
      "who": "ATL User",
      "when": ISODate("2019-04-19T17:11:36Z")
  }
}
```

The issue here is that if a document has multiple sub-documents - or versions - then the query returns those as well instead of omitting them, leaving only the maximum date (if item `Test` had three versions, then three `Test` documents get returned).

What should I be looking at in order to negate those other documents with this query?

```
db.items.aggregate([
    {$match: {subcategory: "Programming Languages", name: {$exists: true}}}, 
    {$project: {"name": 1, 
                "category": 1,
                "subcategory": 1,
                "status": 1,
                "description": 1,
                "change.who": 1,
                "change.when": {$max: "$change.when"}}},
    {$unwind: "$change"},
    {$sort: {"change.when": -1}}
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, let's show your data in a way people can use it and produce a desired result:

```
{ value: 1,
  _id: ObjectId('5cb9ea0c75c61525e0176f96'),
  name: 'Test',
  category: 'Development',
  subcategory: 'Programming Languages',
  status: 'Supported',
  description: 'Test',
  change:
   [ { version: 1,
       who: 'ATL User',
       when: new Date('2019-04-19T15:30:39.912Z'),
       what: 'Item Creation' },
     { version: 2,
       who: 'ATL Other User',
       when: new Date('2019-04-19T15:31:39.912Z'),
       what: 'Name Change' } ],
}
```

Note that the `"when"` dates are in fact different so there will be a [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) value and they are not just the same. Now we can run through the cases

### Case 1 - Fetch the "singular" [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) value

The basic case here is to use the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) and [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) operators to return the matching [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) value:

```
db.items.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "subcategory": "Programming Languages", "name": { "$exists": true }
  }}, 
  { "$addFields": {
    "change": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$change",
        { "$indexOfArray": [
          "$change.when",
          { "$max": "$change.when" }
        ]}
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Returns:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cb9ea0c75c61525e0176f96"),
        "value" : 1,
        "name" : "Test",
        "category" : "Development",
        "subcategory" : "Programming Languages",
        "status" : "Supported",
        "description" : "Test",
        "change" : {
                "version" : 2,
                "who" : "ATL Other User",
                "when" : ISODate("2019-04-19T15:31:39.912Z"),
                "what" : "Name Change"
        }
}
```

Basically the `"$max": "$change.when"` returns the value which is the "maximum" from within that array of values. You then find the matching "index" of that array of values via [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) which returns the **first** matching index found. That "index" position ( from actually just an array of `"when"` values transposed in the same order ) is then used with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to extract the "whole object" from the `"change"` array at the specified index position.

### Case 2 - Return the "multiple" [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) entries

Pretty much the same thing with [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/), except this time we [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to return the multiple *"possible"* values matching that [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) value:

```
db.items.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "subcategory": "Programming Languages", "name": { "$exists": true }
  }}, 
  { "$addFields": {
    "change": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$change",
        "cond": {
          "$eq": [ "$$this.when", { "$max": "$change.when" } ]
        }
      }       
    }
  }}
])
```

Returns:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cb9ea0c75c61525e0176f96"),
        "value" : 1,
        "name" : "Test",
        "category" : "Development",
        "subcategory" : "Programming Languages",
        "status" : "Supported",
        "description" : "Test",
        "change" : [
                {
                        "version" : 2,
                        "who" : "ATL Other User",
                        "when" : ISODate("2019-04-19T15:31:39.912Z"),
                        "what" : "Name Change"
                }
        ]
}
```

So the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) is of course the same but this time the singular value returned by that operator is used in an [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) comparison within [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/). This inspects each array element and looks at the *current* `"when"` value ( `"$$this.when"` ). Where *"equal"* then the element is returned.

Basically the same as the first approach but with the exception that `$filter` allows *"multiple"* elements to be returned. Therefore **everything** with the **same** [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) value.

### Case 3 - Pre-sort the array content.

Now you might note that in the example data I included ( adapted from your own but with an actual "max" date ) the "max" value is in fact the **last** value in the array. This may just naturally happen as a result that [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) ( by default ) *"appends"* to the end of the existing array content. So *"newer"* entries will tend to be at the *end* of the array.

This of course is the *default* behavior, but there are good reasons why you *"may"* want to change that. In short the **best** way to get the *"most recent"* array entry is to in fact return the **first element** from the array.

All you actually need to do is ensure the *"most recent"* is actually added **first** rather than *last*. There are two approaches:

1. **Use [`$position`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) to "pre-pend" array items:** This is a simple modifier to [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) using the `0` *position* in order to always add to the **front**:

   ```
   db.items.updateOne(
     { "_id" : ObjectId("5cb9ea0c75c61525e0176f96") },
     { "$push": {
         "change": {
           "$each": [{
             "version": 3,
             "who": "ATL User",
             "when": new Date(),
             "what": "Another change"
           }],
           "$position": 0
         }
      }}
   )
   ```

   This would change the document to:

   ```
   {
       "_id" : ObjectId("5cb9ea0c75c61525e0176f96"),
       "value" : 1,
       "name" : "Test",
       "category" : "Development",
       "subcategory" : "Programming Languages",
       "status" : "Supported",
       "description" : "Test",
       "change" : [
               {
                       "version" : 3,
                       "who" : "ATL User",
                       "when" : ISODate("2019-04-20T02:40:30.024Z"),
                       "what" : "Another change"
               },
               {
                       "version" : 1,
                       "who" : "ATL User",
                       "when" : ISODate("2019-04-19T15:30:39.912Z"),
                       "what" : "Item Creation"
               },
               {
                       "version" : 2,
                       "who" : "ATL Other User",
                       "when" : ISODate("2019-04-19T15:31:39.912Z"),
                       "what" : "Name Change"
               }
       ]
   }
   ```

Note that this would require you to actually go and "reverse" all your array elements beforehand so that the "newest" was at the front already so the order was maintained. Thankfully this is somewhat covered in the second approach...

2. **Use [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) to modify the documents in order on each [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/):** And this is the other modifier which actually "re-sorts" atomically on every new item addition. Normal usage is basically the same with any new items to [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) as above, or even just an "empty" array in order to apply the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) to existing data only:

   ```
   db.items.updateOne(
     { "_id" : ObjectId("5cb9ea0c75c61525e0176f96") },
     { "$push": {
         "change": {
           "$each": [],
           "$sort": { "when": -1 } 
         }
      }}
   )
   ```

   Results in:

   ```
   {
           "_id" : ObjectId("5cb9ea0c75c61525e0176f96"),
           "value" : 1,
           "name" : "Test",
           "category" : "Development",
           "subcategory" : "Programming Languages",
           "status" : "Supported",
           "description" : "Test",
           "change" : [
                   {
                           "version" : 3,
                           "who" : "ATL User",
                           "when" : ISODate("2019-04-20T02:40:30.024Z"),
                           "what" : "Another change"
                   },
                   {
                           "version" : 2,
                           "who" : "ATL Other User",
                           "when" : ISODate("2019-04-19T15:31:39.912Z"),
                           "what" : "Name Change"
                   },
                   {
                           "version" : 1,
                           "who" : "ATL User",
                           "when" : ISODate("2019-04-19T15:30:39.912Z"),
                           "what" : "Item Creation"
                   }
           ]
   }
   ```

   It might take a minute to absorb why you would [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) in order to [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) an array like this, but the general intent is when modifications might be made to an array which "alter" a property like a `Date` value being sorted on and you would use such a statement to reflect those changes. Or indeed just add new items with the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) and let it work out.

So why *"store"* the array ordered like this? As mentioned earlier you want the **first** item as the *"most recent"*, and then the query to return that simply becomes:

```
db.items.find(
  {
    "subcategory": "Programming Languages",
    "name": { "$exists": true }
  },
  { "change": { "$slice": 1 } }
)
```

Returns:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cb9ea0c75c61525e0176f96"),
        "value" : 1,
        "name" : "Test",
        "category" : "Development",
        "subcategory" : "Programming Languages",
        "status" : "Supported",
        "description" : "Test",
        "change" : [
                {
                        "version" : 3,
                        "who" : "ATL User",
                        "when" : ISODate("2019-04-20T02:40:30.024Z"),
                        "what" : "Another change"
                }
        ]
}
```

So the [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) can then be used just to extract array items by known indexes. Technically you can just use `-1` there in order to return the *last* item of the array anyway, but the reordering where the most recent is first allows for other things like confirming the last modification was made by a certain user, and/or other conditions like a date range constraint. i.e:

```
db.items.find(
  {
    "subcategory": "Programming Languages",
    "name": { "$exists": true },
    "change.0.who": "ATL User",
    "change.0.when": { "$gt": new Date("2018-04-01") }
  },
  { "change": { "$slice": 1 } }
)
```

Noting here that something like `"change.-1.when"` is an illegal statement, which is basically why we reorder the array so you can use the *legal* `0` for *first* instead of `-1` for *last*.

### Conclusion

So there are several different things you can do, either by using the aggregation approach to filtering the array content or via standard query forms after making some modification to how the data is actually stored. Which one to use depends on your own circumstances, but it should be noted that any of the *standard query forms* will run notably faster than any manipulation via the aggregation framework or any computed operators.

Comment: Neil, this is a fantastic response. Thank you for showing multiple ways to achieve the same goal, really allows me to get a different perspective on the ways this can be tackled. I had no idea about the `$arrayElemAt` and `$indexOfArray` operators, that was a large help in the first section of your response. I had been also looking at `$slice` beforehand a little bit, but was confused with how to get that working with the sorted array. Your answer(s) cleared many things up for me and I am very grateful you took the time for this!